# Correct way to mock decorated method in Python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-decorators

I have the class with `.upload` method. This method is wrapped using the decorator:

```
@retry(tries=3)
def upload(self, xml_file: BytesIO):
    self.client.upload(self._compress(xml_file))
```

I need to test if it runs 3 times if some exception occurs.
My test looks like:

```
@mock.patch("api.exporter.jumbo_uploader.JumboZipUploader.upload")
def test_upload_xml_fail(self, mock_upload):
    """Check if decorator called the compress function 3 times"""

    generator = BrandBankXMLGenerator()
    file = generator.generate()

    uploader = JumboZipUploader()
    uploader.upload = retry(mock_upload)
    mock_upload.side_effect = Exception("Any exception")
    uploader.upload(file)

    self.assertEqual(mock_upload.call_count, 3)
```

I have read that the default behavior of python decorators assumes that the function inside the test will be unwrapped and I need to wrap it manually.

I did that trick, but the code fails with AssertionError: 0 != 3.

So, what is the right way here to wrap the decorated method properly?

Comment: I do not understand your example. Could you please provide a minimal working example including only the relevant parts of: a) the code you want to test, b) the code that the is called by a) and that you need to mock, and, c) an example test case which exercises the code from a) while mocking b).

Comment: Not sure about what `retry` decorator you are using, but it looks as if you are using it wrongly: probably you should write `uploader.upload = retry(tries=3)(mock_upload)`.